# WOL and Sleep Mode

Tags: sleep, wakeonlan, low-power

I have a small ubuntu server set up as a media server and web server for my home network. The usage of the server however is less than 5% of the day, so I am trying to find a neat solution to

- wake up when someone accesses the server
- sleep/hibernate when the server is inactive for more than 10 minutes

Is there a simple solution, or a package already available? or am I going to have to resort to building a set of scripts to do this for me?

I am running 10.04LTS, in a headless server mode.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards